# get next location of element in array instead of first with indexOf

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm using `arr.indexOf('NN')` to obtain the first location of 'NN' in array arr. How can I obtain the second / next location of 'NN' in the array after the first. Or even after location `i`, if I am traversing the array in a for loop?

Comment: Ever thought of checking documentation first? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: If you iterate over the array anyway, just compare each entry with your value?

Comment: @zerkms it shows `.lastindexOf()` not nextIndexOf()

Comment: check the second parameter of `indexOf()`; it specify the position to start the search

Comment: @MrGuru: what if you check the `.indexOf()` documentation then?

Comment: @LeoZhuang Thank you, but how do I give it a location to stop the search. So I want to grab from location i until the next instance that has 'NN'?

Comment: `arr.indexOf('NN', i)`. Or if by "location i" you mean "n-th occurrence of NN", you are applying `.indexOf` repeatedly and count.

Answer (score 0):

This will log an array with all the indices where the contained values match 'NN' :

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,'NN',5,6,'NN',8,9];

var locations = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if(arr[i] === 'NN'){
    locations.push(i);
  }
}

console.log(locations); // => [4,7]
```

Comment: Hello, if you found this answers useful, please select it as the official answer. Building reputations helps a lot on this site. Thank you!